# Skip reading an empty file in for loop in R

Tags: r, xml, for-loop

I have around 1 million XML files from which I am trying to extract the tagnames and data.  The following is an example of the XML file.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <IOTModellerLog xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" DeviceID="7430180" ClientID="12324" FileCreationDate="2017-03-01T22:40:03" FileVersion="2" EventClassID="65535" IOTLogCreationDate="2017-03-01T12:29:54" SampleID="1" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="/opt/nds/ams_proxy/webapps/ams_proxy/WEB-INF/amsXmlSchema.xsd">
       <Event EventTime="2017-02-27T18:33:58">
          <IOTEvent State="PowerOn" />
       </Event>
       <Event EventTime="2017-02-28T08:59:03">
          <DataEvent>
             <Model>1</Model>
             <DataType>1</DataType>
             <DataValue>0301</DataValue>
          </DataEvent>
       </Event>
       <Event EventTime="2017-02-28T08:59:13">
          <DataEvent>
             <Model>1</Model>
             <DataType>1</DataType>
             <DataValue>0401</DataValue>
          </DataEvent>
       </Event>
    </IOTModellerLog>
```

I use the following function to parse the xml data.
    library(XML)
    library(data.table)

```
parse_xml <-function(FileName) {
  xmldata <- xmlParse(FileName)
  result_nodes = XML::getNodeSet(xmldata , "//IOTModellerLog/Event")
  abc <- rbindlist(lapply(result_nodes,function(x) data.frame(as.list(unlist(xmlToList(x))))),use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE) 
  abc <- data.frame(lapply(abc, as.character), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)  
}
```

I am using this function in a for loop to extract the tag names first.

```
for (i in 1:length(files)) {
    dat <- parse_xml(files[i])
    namesdat = names(dat)
    output <- c(output,namesdat)
    output <- unique(output)    
}
```

However I receive some files that has only the meta data related to the device and not the event data.  For example:

```
<IOTModellerLog xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" DeviceID="7430180" ClientID="12324" FileCreationDate="2017-03-01T22:40:03" FileVersion="2" EventClassID="65535" IOTLogCreationDate="2017-03-01T12:29:54" SampleID="1" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="/opt/nds/ams_proxy/webapps/ams_proxy/WEB-INF/amsXmlSchema.xsd">

</IOTModellerLog>
```

When the for loop encounters this file, it stops with an error indicating that it could not find the columns, essentially meaning it could not find the data.

I tried adding this in the for loop

```
if (length(namesdat) == 0 ) next
```

Similarly I tried adding an if clause in the parse XML function allowing only if the `length(result_nodes)` greater than zero.  This too didn't work.

Comment: on which line specifically does it now error?

Comment: In the parse_xml `function abc <- rbindlist(lapply(result_nodes,function(x) data.frame(as.list(unlist(xmlToList(x))))),use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE)`

Comment: Since the previous line `result_nodes = XML::getNodeSet(xmldata , "//IOTModellerLog/Event")` is empty

Comment: then you may need two `if()` - i) if result_nodes is empty `return(NULL)` and ii) in the loop `if (is.null(dat)) next`